Double category of monads and pseudo monad-morphisms
We can construct bicategories of monads in a bicategory $B$, $Mnd_l(B)$/$Mnd_c(B)$ with lax and colax monad-morphisms respectively.
I am failing to find a good notion of pseudo monad-morphisms.
Is there a good notion of such a monad morphism in literature? The rest applies whether it is explicitly written down or not. Just hopefully it can coincide with some pseudo-notion in the literature.
Can we construct a double category of monads and lax/colax monad-morphisms and use it to define pseudo monad-morphisms?
What I mean concretely is having a double category of monads where horizontal/vertical 2-categories are $Mnd_l(B)$/$Mnd_c(B)$, preferably such that these are each lax/colax 2-categories of algebras for the same monad $T$ in some (other) bicategory and the whole double category is the double category of algebras for $T$. With the pseudo monad-morphism arising as conjoint pairs. If there are multiple such double categories, what is the space of choices for 2-cells in these double categories?
Is there a preferred notion of 2-cells in such a double category?

A pseudo morphism is simply an invertible lax morphism (equivalently an invertible colax morphism).

Yea, that's what i would expect. Not sure if it makes sense for them to arrange into a double category of algebras for some monad

oh they should indeed be conjoint pairs, i have to write it up.

(To clarify, I should have said "with invertible 2-cell component"; the 1-cell in the data of a co/lax morphism is not altered.)

Companion pairs, not conjoint pairs.

A monad in a strict 2-category $K$ is equivalent to a monoid in some strict monoidal endomorphism category $K(x,x)$, which is equivalent to a strict monoidal functor $\Delta_a \to K(x,x)$ where $\Delta_a$ is the augmented simplex category, which is equivalent to a strict 2-functor $B \Delta_a \to K$ where $B\Delta_a$ is the 1-object 2-category corresponding to $\Delta_a$ and the object is sent to $x$.  You can check that with monads thusly identified, lax, colax, and pseudo monad morphisms correspond respectively to lax, colax, and pseudo natural transformations of 2-functors $B \Delta_a \to K$.
More generally, for any 2-categories $C$ and $K$ there is a double category $[C,K]$ whose objects are 2-functors, whose morphisms are lax and colax transformations, and whose companion pairs are (equivalent to) pseudo transformations.  If $C$ is small and $K$ is cocomplete, this is the double category of algebras for a monad on $K^{\mathrm{ob}(C)}$ (and if $K$ is complete, for a comonad thereon), defined by $T(X)_c = \sum_{d} X_d \cdot C(d,c)$.
All this also holds up to equivalence when $K$ is a bicategory.

Is there a nice counterexample for the general form when K is not cocomplete?

Just that the $\sum$ and the $\cdot$ might not exist.

hmm, what i was thinking is a bit more abstract. Are there 2-categories C and K, (K is not cocomplete), such that the double category [C,K] can not be a double category of algebras for any monad on some bicategory, not just the one in answer?

No idea, sorry.
